# Notification disappearing randomly without cancelling them

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

The notification of my program disappear randomly. Sometimes after few seconds, sometimes I cannot even see them, some other times they remains until I cancel them manually (which is the behaviour I want).

My notifications are launched by a Service, which is called regularly by a JobService.
The following function is called in StartService. Thanks to the vibrating, I can say the function is called. But I do not understand why the notification disappear. I did not cancel the notification (no cancelAll either). I think it may be because my service die, but it's the normal cycle of a service, when I do want the notification to stay at screen...

Thanks for your help!

```
// create notification
private void SendDummyNotification() {
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, ActivityParam.class), FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification notification;

        notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("test notification")
                .setContentText("dummy")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setShowWhen(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_LOW)
                .build();


    // add notification 
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1998, notification);

    // vibrate
    Vibrator t_vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    t_vibrator.vibrate(2000);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I called the notification through a service started by a jobservice. I changed that: the notification is now launched by the jobservice. I do not have the problem anymore.